# How to sign a java applet and setting permissions to read system properties such as the logged on user of a client

Tags: java, applet

Could someone please help me with how to sign an applet and make it successfully get the value of System.getProperty("user.name"). Shall have to edit user policy files and how do I do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with policy files, they are impractical for real world deployment.

To get trust, digitally sign the code, and explain to the user why it is necessary for them to accept trusted code.

There is a small archive at my JNLP API demos. page that contains code & build files for a [trusted JWS app.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  Import that into an IDE and see how it works.  It is for an application, but the same signing techniques apply to an applet.

---

And as a 'fall-back method' for Sun JREs on Windows, which will load the applet as sand-boxed if the user refuses the digitally signed code.

Pop a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` that requests the user provide their own user name.  Heck if they can't do that, it is doubtful they could be trusted to use an app. that requires log-in.  ;)

Even better for Windows (and *nix) machines that have the plug-in 2 architecture JRE, use the `PeristenceService` of the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) API of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to serialize the user names and present a list at start up (probably in an editable `JComboBox` to accommodate new users).

Comment: +1 It's an excellent opportunity to instruct users how to examine the certificate critically.

Comment: @trashgod: Yes.  And on that topic, warn them that the reason a self-signed app. gets the warnings it does, is that a self-signed cert. is 'not worth the bits it is written on'.  Disclaimer:  I use a self-signed cert. for all my projects, since a verified one is too expensive.  My users can trust the code coming from my site, or not.  ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I managed to self sign my applet. Continue the great work!