# How to grant applet permission to read system properties?

Tags: java, applet, system-properties

I have a Java applet that is trying to read the `http.strictPostRedirect` **System Property**.

The code is not mine (it's Java's; so i cannot change it). But you can find the code online:

**HttpURLConnection.java**:

```
if (method.equals("POST") && !Boolean.getBoolean("http.strictPostRedirect") && (stat!=307)) 
{
   /* The HTTP/1.1 spec says that a redirect from a POST 
    * *should not* be immediately turned into a GET, and
    * that some HTTP/1.0 clients incorrectly did this.
    * Correct behavior redirects a POST to another POST.
    * Unfortunately, since most browsers have this incorrect
    * behavior, the web works this way now.  Typical usage
    * seems to be:
    *   POST a login code or passwd to a web page.
    *   after validation, the server redirects to another
    *     (welcome) page
    *   The second request is (erroneously) expected to be GET
    * 
    * We will do the incorrect thing (POST-->GET) by default.
    * We will provide the capability to do the "right" thing
    * (POST-->POST) by a system property, "http.strictPostRedirect=true"
    */
    ...
}
```

The basic failure comes from calling:

```
Boolean.getBoolean("http.strictPostRedirect")
```

Which has caused a [lot of people grief](http://www.coderanch.com/t/355819/Servlets/java/PropertyPermission-exception-thrown-posting-Serlvet). Apparently i'm not *allowed* to read the `http.strictPostRedirect` System Property. Trying to *read* it throws an **AccessControlException**:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission http.strictPostRedirect read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(Unknown Source)
```

So, if i don't have permission to *read* permission to a **System Property**:

> How do i get read permission to a system property?

There obviously must be a setting that *gives* me permission to read a system property, otherwise Sun wouldn't have code that transparently tries to access it.

Is it a machine world-wide setting? Is it a domain-wide setting? Is it a machine-wide setting? Is it a per-user setting? Is it a per-applet setting? Is it a per-invocation setting? Is it a setting tied to a particular version of the *Java Runtime Engine*?

**tl;dr**: How make not crash?

## Reading system properties

Java does have a [list of **system properties** than at applet cannot read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/properties.html):

- `java.class.path`
- `java.home`
- `user.dir`
- `user.home`
- `user.name`

My **system property**, `http.strictPostRedirect`, is not on that list. So why can't i read it?

### See also

- [`HttpURLConnection.java`](https://community.cablelabs.com/svn/OCAPRI/tags/ri/release/ODLSrc_TWB_1.0.1_ER1_FINAL/OCAP-1.0/jvm/Sun/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java)
- [HttpURLConnection redirects my POST request into a GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246557/httpurlconnection-redirects-my-post-request-into-a-get)
- [PropertyPermission exception thrown when posting to Serlvet](http://www.coderanch.com/t/355819/Servlets/java/PropertyPermission-exception-thrown-posting-Serlvet)
- [Access Denied Error](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1053340?start=0&tstart=0)
- [java.security.AccessControlException](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t135029-java-security-accesscontrolexception.html)
- [How to sign a java applet and setting permissions to read system properties such as the logged on user of a client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704992/how-to-sign-a-java-applet-and-setting-permissions-to-read-system-properties-such)
- [how to provide access permission for applet to write on file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660646/how-to-provide-access-permission-for-applet-to-write-on-file-system)
- [Using Java SecurityManager to grant/deny access to system functions](http://www.javablogging.com/using-java-securitymanager-to-grantdeny-access-to-system-functions/)
- [Oracle.com - What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'fix' here is to digitally sign the applet, then convince the user to OK the code when prompted.

---

> Java does have a list of system properties than at applet cannot read:
>
> - java.class.path
> - java.home
> - user.dir
> - user.home
> - user.name
>
> My system property, http.strictPostRedirect, is not on that list. So why can't i read it?

That is the 'short list' of properties that a sand-boxed app. cannot read.  There are also many more.  E.G. nothing under `user` is permitted<sup>1</sup>. Just consider those to be 'typical'.

1. Output for [7 `user` properties](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=user.country%2Cuser.dir%2Cuser.home%2Cuser.language%2Cuser.name%2Cuser.timezone%2Cuser.variant&format=TSV) in a sand-boxed app.

---

```
Name            Value
user.country    unknown
user.dir        unknown
user.home       unknown
user.language   unknown
user.name       unknown
user.timezone   unknown
user.variant    unknown
```

---

> There obviously must be a setting that gives me permission to read a system property, otherwise Sun wouldn't have code that transparently tries to access it.

True.  See the fix above.

---